# C++, User input of letters, numbers, and spaces into a string

Tags: c++, string, input

So I have a small problem and I can't find an elegant solution to it.

I'm asking the user to input their address. How would I put that into a string? It would contain letters, numbers, and spaces. I tried the getline function but no success with that.

> cout << "\nEnter customer street address" << endl;
>   cin >> address;

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that you'll want to use a `string` and `getline`.

```
string address;
cout << "\nEnter customer street address: ";
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()); // May or may not be needed.
getline(cin, address);
```

[string Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)
[getline Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
[numeric_limits Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/)

Comment: when i try getline(cin, address); it just skips over it and doesnt get user input, why?

Comment: @WhatThePhil, very odd, but see my edit. That should take care of it.

Comment: @David actually when I use cin.ignore it doesn't work for me (using onlinegdb C++17)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

```
int main()
{
    // greet the user
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << ", nice to meet you.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said:

```
  string address;
  cout << "\nEnter customer street address: ";
  getline(cin, address);
```

With this your input can be typed until user hits enter (newline);

If you want multiple line input you'll still need some stop criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You should use getLine like that:

```
string address;
cout << "\nEnter customer street address: ";
cin.getLine(address,MaxLengthOfAddress,\n);
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getline-string-c/